# Is there a way to run command in Visual Studio Code from CLI?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I'd like to run a script for open Visual Studio Code from command line and passing a command to the integrated terminal. Something like

```
#!/bin/bash

code /path/to/my/project --run-in-terminal "docker start my-db-container; npm start"
```

nb. `--run-in-terminal` option does not exists

I'm also considering writing an exension to do so, but I can't find how to interact with integrated terminal.
I know it's harmful, it's only for educational purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try creating a task that runs whenever you open the workspace (tasks.json):

```
{
  "label": "run docker start on open folder",
  "command": "docker start my-db-container; npm start",
  "type": "shell",
  "problemMatcher": [],
  "runOptions": {"runOn": "folderOpen"}
},
```

There is a bit of a delay before the task is triggered.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. btw the correct "command" syntax is `"command": ["docker start my-db-container; npm start"]`